# iOS Beta app added to App Store Connect and approved, but not visible in iOS TestFlight App

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect, testflight

I have an app in App Store Connect, previous versions was visible in iOS TestFlight and my users could test it, but after uploading latest build, and getting approved by review team, it's not visible in Test Flight app and users can't install it.

I wrote for apple and and waited a couple of days, still no change.

What shall I do? Resubmit another build?

Answer (score 0):

FYI:

I waited a couple of days, no success, so I uploaded new build, now it showed up in users' TestFlight and users started updating the app!